# async Ajax during page navigation

Tags: jquery, ajax, asynchronous, asp.net-ajax

We have lot of widgets and each have  its own save.when we are doing an page navigation we are trying to save each widget data of  so we are almost making 10-15 ajax calls. We tried in window.onbeforeunload event but only some of the ajax calls were successful then we turn off async calls (async:true) but this is causing performance hit. can we make async to work. Below is the code

```
 if ($.browser.mozilla) {

        window.onunload = function () {
            onunloadSave();
        };            
    } else {

        window.onbeforeunload = function () {
            onunloadSave();
        };
    } 

    function onunloadSave() {
        //debugger;
        var chckSave = CheckIsSave();
        var checkBilling = CheckIsBilling();
       // var checkSwitch = CheckLoginSwitch();
        if (chckSave == false && checkBilling == false ) {
            if ($('#examtypes').val() > 0) {

                $.when(saveWidgets()).then(function () {
                    //dosomething
                });

            }
        }
    }`//below will make 10-15 ajax calls
function saveWidgets() {
    $('#examArea button[id*=btnSave], #exambar button[id*=btnSave]').click();
}
```

Comment: please provide some example of your code to make more easy to regenerate your problem

Comment: Chris - I added code